# php-mqtt/client subscribing fails

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, mqtt, phpmqtt

I'am trying to get messages over mqtt to my webserver written in php. For mqtt I used https://github.com/php-mqtt/client this for php.

My Problem now is this line: `$mqtt->load(true);`. When I try to open my Website (the website is on my raspberry-pi apache2) the website does not open! Instead the website loads very long till this error appears.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\DataTransferException: [65] Transferring data over socket failed: Sending data over the socket failed. Has it been closed? in /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php:1158 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(1112): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->writeToSocket() #1 /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(1081): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->writeToSocketWithAutoReconnect() #2 /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(696): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->ping() #3 /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php(652): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->loopOnce() #4 /var/www/html/phptest2.php(13): PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient->loop() #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php on line 1158
```

My Code:
(In github is the same code, I only use it to test)

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$server   = 'broker.hivemq.com';
$port     = 1883;
$clientId = 'test-subscriber';

use PhpMqtt\Client\MQTTClient;
$mqtt = new \PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId);
$mqtt->connect();
$mqtt->subscribe('php-mqtt/client/test', function ($topic, $message, $retained, $matchedWildcards) {
    echo sprintf("Received message on topic [%s]: %s\n", $topic, $message);
}, 0);
$mqtt->loop();
$mqtt->disconnect();
?>
```

The Programm should display the messages. But it does not work and I have no Ideas why.The Publish method works fine.

Comment: Pass a logger to the constructor of `MqttClient` (see [examples](https://github.com/php-mqtt/client-examples)) for more details. I could imagine that `test-subscriber` is a name on the public HiveMQ broker that is already in use. But it could also be the connection settings. Maybe also try `$mqtt->loop(true)` to allow sleeping, which saves a bit of CPU.

Comment: An MQTT subscription results in a stream of messages (the connection could, in theory, remain open for months and receive 0-∞ messages). HTTP is a request/response (give me this page, OK there you go). Combining these can be tricky - in your example `$mqtt->loop();` will block indefinitely. You could wait for one message and then exit (see [this example](https://github.com/php-mqtt/client-examples/blob/master/02_subscribing/01_subscribe_with_qos_0.php#L32)) but this really depends upon your end goal.